# Change excel file extension from xls to xlsx while uploading with php

Tags: php, excel, file-upload

Is it possible and if is how can i change excel file extension while uploading or before saving file on server? I am using php and mysql.

Thankyou

Comment: This makes no sense. .xls is a binary format. .xlsx is actually a zip container with xml / binaries inside. Changing the extension would therefore cause errors upon trying to load the files.

Comment: You can rename your file to whatever you would like but you should not do it. `.xls` extension is specific for Microsoft Office prior to 2007 and just changing its extension doesn't mean that you are converting the file to a later one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], upload_PATH.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'].'x');
```

But that will **only change the file** name with the xlsx extension. It will **not actually convert** the file to xlsx format.

Comment: Is it possible to actually convert file?

Comment: For that you will have to use the PHPExcel library. You'll find it here

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ ... Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned in a different reply, changing the extension won't actually change the format, and it's not a good idea to serve a .xls file as .xlsx, since this will only confuse anyone trying to read it.

What you could do (disregarding potential problems with converting and verification of the file) is read the uploaded file into a library like PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) and then use the builtin functions to export it as an .xlsx file. Sample below:

```
// Create a reader to read .xls format
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
// Read the .xls file from upload storage
$workbook = $reader->load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

// Create a writer to output in .xlsx format
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($workbook, 'Excel2007');
// Save file to destination .xlsx path
$writer->save($destination_path);
```

Keep in mind that although this might work perfectly well, the conversion might mess with the contents of the file. This might not be desirable, as the conversion *can* cause data loss, formatting changes and all sorts of weirdness.